# Wrap related models using ngResource in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-resource

I have following resources in frontend:

```
.factory('TaskComment', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/api/me/task-comments/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
         object: {method: 'GET', params: {id: ''}, isArray: false},
         query: {method: 'GET', params: {id: ''}, isArray: true},
         create: {method: 'POST', isArray: false},
         update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}
     });
 })
 .factory('User', function ($resource) {
     var User = $resource('/api/me/users/:id', {id: '@id'}, {
         object: {method: 'GET', params: {id: ''}, isArray: false},
         query: {method: 'GET', params: { id: ''}, isArray: true},
         create: {method: 'POST', isArray: false},
         update: {method: 'PUT', isArray: false}
     });

     User.prototype.getAvatarUrl = function () {
         if (this.avatar) {
             return '/media/' + this.avatar;
         } else {
             return '/static/images/no-avatar.png';
         }
     };

     return User;
 })
```

When I select user using User resource like this:

```
User.object({id: 1}, function(response) {user = response})
```

I can use `getAvatarUrl` method `user.getAvatarUrl()` in controllers or in templates, but when I select Comment, witch contains related model User, I can't use getAvatarUrl method becouse it's simple JS object. Example:

```
TaskComment.object({id: 1}, function(response) {
    var comment = response; 
    comment.user.getAvatarUrl() // Error: method does not exist

    comment.user = new User(comment.user)
    comment.user.getAvatarUrl() // OK
})
```

The question: there is way to write a code, that will automatically wrap comment.user for all select queries?